# jQuery script in html head not working

Tags: jquery, html

My jQuery works fine when it is in an external document but not when I put it in the head of the document. Here's the code:

```
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta id="myViewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>My title</title>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/responsive_styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Serif" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/7c396dc5cb.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore;
                var iOS = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.MSStream;

                if (isChrome){ 
                    $(".welcome-background").css("background-attachment", "scroll");
                    $(".menu-background").css("background-attachment", "scroll");
                    $(".openHours-background").css("background-attachment", "scroll");
                }

                if(iOS){
                    $(".welcome-background").css("background-attachment", "scroll");
                    $(".menu-background").css("background-attachment", "scroll");
                    $(".openHours-background").css("background-attachment", "scroll");
                }
            });   
        </script>
    </head>
```

Comment: I can't see the reference to jQuery

Comment: javascript 101 where is the jquery script? before your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not included `jQuery` library, It should come before `jQuery` scripts.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta id="myViewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My title</title>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/responsive_styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Serif" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/7c396dc5cb.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore;
            var iOS = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.MSStream;

            if (isChrome){ 
                $(".welcome-background").css("background-attachment", "scroll");
                $(".menu-background").css("background-attachment", "scroll");
                $(".openHours-background").css("background-attachment", "scroll");
            }

            if(iOS){
                $(".welcome-background").css("background-attachment", "scroll");
                $(".menu-background").css("background-attachment", "scroll");
                $(".openHours-background").css("background-attachment", "scroll");
            }
        });   
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks I had the jQuery library at the bottom of the body which worked fine before

Answer (score 0):

You need to import your `jquery` first before your `javascript` code.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      alert('Reece your jQUERY is now ready! :)'); // Check if jquery has been loaded.
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

That's it..Happy Coding! :)